# Why can this update query solve the concurrency problem?

Tags: concurrency

update Wallet set balance = balance-10 where idWallet = 'x' and balance >= 10;

While reading about the concurrency of the update query statement, I saw that this query statement solves concurrency.
But if you think about it, let's say we have transaction A and transaction B.
If transactions A and B execute update at the same time, transaction A accesses the stockQuantity property and has a value, and transaction B also has the stockQuantity value at the same time, I think concurrency will not be resolved, but this query statement Why are you solving this concurrency?

I performed 5000 times in a multi-threaded environment with 1000000 thread pools, but concurrency was resolved.